# .htaccess - route to selected desination but change browser url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Problem:
I'd like to accept the original request. Say its, /IWantToGoHere/index.php
but I want to return to the browser, /GoHere/index.php

To be clear:
I actually want to send the original request location down to the script requested, however, I want to return the user a browser URL to another destination.

Code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)IWantToGoHere\/\.php$  GoHere/index.php [NC,C]
RewriteRule ^GoHere/index.php$ GoHere/index.php [R,NC]
```

Notes:
I realize the code above doesn't work.  I've tried a number of different calls.  I spent umpteen hours yesterday trying every clever solution I could pull out of my limited mod_rewrite knowledge bank.  Based on my understanding of mod_rewrite, I don't think it's do able.  I understand its not what the preprocessed was designed to do.  At least not from anything I could find on the Apache web site.  I've been told that if I could dream it up, that it could be done:) I was wondering if anyone had and ideas how to get it to work.

Why would you want to do that?:
Because I do.  No really, I want the URL returned to the user for further processing.

weez

Comment: I suggest you re-think your URL patterns.  Come up with a good "public" URL schema, and use mod_rewrite to rewrite those to your "internal" schema.  What you are talking about is madness.

Comment: You don’t need to escape the `/` character; Apache does not use Perl-like delimiters. But the `.` needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, to accomplish this you'll need to send a header from `/IWantToGoHere/index.php` that redirects to `/GoHere/index.php` once the script is finished executing. That is, if you want Apache to still call `IWantToGoHere` but return to `GoHere`. So at the end of processing for `IWantToGoHere` script something like this:

`header('Location: /GoHere/Index.php');`

Which will redirect correctly.

Comment: pyborex1: Yeah, I think you follow where I'm going with this. Hmm... I didn't think about that. I suppose as long as my controller (I'm using a MVC pattern) has sent any output headers, that might possibly work. Lemme give it a shot. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Good thing controllers aren't views, so shouldn't ever output any content.